# how can i invoke NDK's method in arm linux?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have an NDK 'so' file for AES Encryption, which I unpacked from an apk. But I don't know the ASE key. This file is used to send encrypted commands and then decrypt the response. Now I want to use this file on other platform except Android(for example, an ARM base Ubuntu).How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to fake Android RT environment on Ubuntu. First, look for all unresolved symbols in the SO, and the dynamic libs it expects. Then, write your custom implementation of these functions using a native ARM based Ubuntu toolchain.